# Gradle Copy Typed Task configures without error but equivalent non-typed task with copy closure fails

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I am new to Gradle and am exploring it's file manipulation features, namely `Copy`, `Zip` and the likes. According to the [DSL documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:copy(groovy.lang.Closure)), a `Project` has a `zipTree` method, that should be called with a `zipPath Object` that is usually evaluated per the `file` method. It also advises combining the method with the `copy` method to unzip a ZIP file, of which `copy` accepts a closure to configure a `CopySpec` that defines the file copying itself.

In the example I am exploring, the `task` doing the unzipping manipulates a file that is as of yet non-existent at the start of the Gradle configuration process; it `dependsOn` another `task` that first ZIPs the relevant files, as seen below.

```
task bundleWeb(type: Zip){
    destinationDir = file('build')
    baseName 'web'
    from 'build/web'
    exclude 'images/**'
}
```

Initially, I tried to unzip the `build/web.zip` file using a non-typed task.

```
task unpackBundle(dependsOn: bundleWeb){
    copy{
        from zipTree('build/web.zip')
        into 'build/exploded'
    }
}
```

However, this failed miserably to my surprise; the build failed, saying:

> Cannot expand ZIP
>   '.../1.11-Exercise-ConfigureFileSystemTasks/build/web.zip'
>   as it does not exist.

However, by giving the `task` the `Copy type`, and removing the closure, the `Project` builds smoothly and runs as expected.

```
task unpackBundle(type: Copy, dependsOn: bundleWeb){
    from zipTree('build/web.zip')
    into 'build/exploded'
}
```

How would this be possible? Am I understanding the usage of the `project.copy()` function incorrectly? Or do `typed tasks` do something different in the way they are configured?

Disclaimer: Examples are all modified from Udacity's Gradle for Android and Java course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
task unpackBundle(dependsOn: bundleWeb) {
    copy {
        from zipTree('build/web.zip')
        into 'build/exploded'
    }
}
```

This executes the copy while *configuring* the task, before any task has been executed. You want to execute the copy when *executing* the task:

```
task unpackBundle(dependsOn: bundleWeb){
    doLast {
        copy {
            from zipTree('build/web.zip')
            into 'build/exploded'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whoops! my bad. thanks for highlighting it. to clarify, why did the compiler not complain in the typed task when I called the zipTree method?

Comment: A task without type doesn't do anything other than what you tell it to do using the doLast method. A task which has a type does what its type defines as its task action: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html

Comment: Because zipTree returns a lazy zip tree. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:zipTree(java.lang.Object)

Comment: I see. I just experimented, putting an additional action through doLast{} on the Copy typed task did not actually run the action; so for typed tasks, no additional actions can run?

Comment: doLast are executed, whether or not the task is typed. But of course, the task itself needs to be executed. If it's up--to-date, nothing will happen.

Comment: ah yes. just got familiarised with incremental builds. it appears I need to delve deeper into Gradle to fully comprehend some of its behaviours, thanks for the help!